# Excel VBA, error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method on WorksheetFunction

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

So I am getting the error in the title on the AT_cellnum line where I use the address function.

---

```
Sub AllTransURL()

Dim AT_rownum As Integer, pathrange As Range, AT_cellnum As String, sheetname As String

sheetname = "All Transmissions"
Set pathrange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All Transmissions").Range("H1:H53")

AT_rownum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("infra/remwip/Public/0_00_Rapports", pathrange, 0)

AT_cellnum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Address(AT_rownum, 1, 1, 1, sheetname)

End Sub
```

---

Thanks you

Comment: `AT_cellnum = Worksheets(sheetname).Range("A" & AT_rownum).Address(1,1,xlA1,1)`

Comment: You can't use that function in VBA as a worksheetfunction, hence your error. If you try to type it out `Worksheetfunction.address` it won't also show like other functions would. Edit: I see @ScottCraner has got you the answer right there. Btw, if you won't find a match this code will give you an error ;)

Comment: But ultimately my guess is that you want to return the value in column A where the match is found.  Skip the address and simply do `AT_cellval = Worksheets(sheetname).Range("A" & AT_rownum).value`

Comment: Thanks Scott, your first answer was exacly what was looking for. Because I don't want the value of that cell but the hyperlink attached to it.   Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for an `Address` function in the object model, hence it's not on the `WorksheetFunction` interface.

Rule of thumb, if you're maknig an early-bound member call and the member you want to invoke isn't showing up in the autocompletion name list, it's not a member of the object you're working with; if the code compiles anyway, there's a good chance it will throw error 438 at run-time.

There's no need for an `Address` function, because when you work with the object model, you have a `Range` object, and `Range` has an `Address` property that's readily available: a `WorksheetFunction` for it would be entirely redundant.

You know what worksheet the range is from (`sheetname`); you know what row you want (`AT_rownum`), and you know what column you want (`1`) - thus:

```
Dim AT_range As Range
Set AT_range = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(AT_rownum, 1)

AT_cellnum = AT_range.Address
```

But as Scott hinted at, a cell's address is rarely something you *need* in VBA: if you have a `Range` object, you likely already have everything you need.